websocket cannot establish connection when I adding custom filter in springboot 3
My service was working well in springboot 2.6(springframework 5 in it),
but after I upgrade to springboot 3.2.4(springframework should be 6),  my websocket server cannot be connected,  client side shows: Error: Unexpected server response: 401
I created a simple springboot project for testing websocket step by step, first created websocket config and handler, then I opened 2 ports one for websocket and another for http request. I added interceptor for websocket,  and filter for http request. All the steps above were working , till I added custom filter registration config, then websocket failed with 401 .
What's wrong here?
here's my codes:

SecurityConfig:

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig  {
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
            ).httpBasic(withDefaults());

    return http.build();
}
}


WebSocketConfig:

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(testingHandler(), "/ws/{id}").setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .addInterceptors(handshakeInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler testingHandler() {
        return new TestingHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public HandshakeInterceptor handshakeInterceptor() {
        return new TestingInterceptor();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletServerContainerFactoryBean createWebSocketContainer() {
        ServletServerContainerFactoryBean container = new ServletServerContainerFactoryBean();
        container.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(WEB_SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE);
        container.setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(WEB_SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE);
        return container;
    }
}

3.ServerConfig -- multipe ports config
@Configuration
public class ServerConfig {


    @Value("${server.additionalPorts}")
    private String additionalPorts;

    /**
     * multi ports config
     */
    @Bean
    public TomcatServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        Connector[] additionalConnectors = this.additionalConnector();
        if (additionalConnectors != null && additionalConnectors.length > 0) {
            tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(additionalConnectors);
        }
        //Invalid character error
        tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers(new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(Connector connector) {
                connector.setProperty("relaxedQueryChars", "|{}[]");
            }
        });
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector[] additionalConnector() {
        if (!StringUtils.hasLength(this.additionalPorts)) {
            return null;
        }
        String[] ports = this.additionalPorts.split(",");
        List<Connector> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String port : ports) {
            Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
            connector.setScheme("http");
            connector.setProperty("relaxedQueryChars", "|{}[]");
            connector.setPort(Integer.valueOf(port));
            result.add(connector);
        }
        return result.toArray(new Connector[] {});
    }
}


WebMvcConfig -- filter registration

@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig{

    @Bean
    public Filter testingFilter(){
        return new TestingFilter();
    }
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<DelegatingFilterProxy> filterRegist() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<DelegatingFilterProxy> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(new DelegatingFilterProxy("testingFilter"));
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/rest/*");//URI path to filter
        registration.setOrder(1);
        return registration;
    }
}

other codes like filter/interceptor/ websocket handler were just test code with empty methods.
If anyone who met this error before, please help me on it,  thank you !

For starters, as you are using Spring Boot, don't do extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport as that disables large parts of the Spring Boot autoconfiguration. What does your TestingFilter actually do?

oh WebMvcConfigurationSupport was unnecessary here, will delete it.
for now it's just a testing project, TestingFilter was empty

If it is empty it doesn't do anything and actually prevents request processing.
